# Kivy nao roda erro no editor de texto

Tags: python, windows, python-kivy

Ola
Acabei de instalar o kivy no windows seguindo o passo-a-passo do site kivy.org.

Quando tento executar um script de teste, recebo mensagem no console do pycharm de que a execução foi abortada: "Unable to get a Text provider, abort."

Todos os pacotes foram descarregados e instalados com êxito.

Alguem pode me dizer o que posso fazer?

segue a copia do command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Paulo>python --version
Python 3.6.2

C:\Users\Paulo>python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\paulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.30.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-38.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 491kB 604kB/s
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 28.8.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-28.8.0:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-28.8.0
Successfully installed setuptools-38.4.0 wheel-0.30.0

C:\Users\Paulo>python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
Collecting docutils
  Downloading docutils-0.14-py3-none-any.whl (543kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 552kB 555kB/s
Collecting pygments
  Downloading Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (841kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 849kB 413kB/s
Collecting pypiwin32
  Downloading pypiwin32-220-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl (9.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 9.0MB 50kB/s
Collecting kivy.deps.sdl2
  Downloading kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.17-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (2.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.5MB 169kB/s
Collecting kivy.deps.glew
  Downloading kivy.deps.glew-0.1.9-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (102kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 1.5MB/s
Installing collected packages: docutils, pygments, pypiwin32, kivy.deps.sdl2, kivy.deps.glew
Successfully installed docutils-0.14 kivy.deps.glew-0.1.9 kivy.deps.sdl2-0.1.17 pygments-2.2.0 pypiwin32-220

C:\Users\Paulo>
C:\Users\Paulo>python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
Collecting kivy.deps.gstreamer
  Downloading kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.12-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (129.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 129.5MB 3.4kB/s
Installing collected packages: kivy.deps.gstreamer
Successfully installed kivy.deps.gstreamer-0.1.12

C:\Users\Paulo>python -m pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
  Downloading Kivy-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (3.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.5MB 124kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: docutils in c:\users\paulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Collecting Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 (from kivy)
  Downloading kivy-garden-0.1.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\paulo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Collecting requests (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Downloading requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.5MB/s
Collecting urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Downloading urllib3-1.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 1.3MB/s
Collecting idna<2.7,>=2.5 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Downloading idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Downloading certifi-2017.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (330kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 337kB 778kB/s
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from requests->Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 143kB 1.0MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: Kivy-Garden
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Kivy-Garden ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Paulo\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\27\08\88\88938a7cf5b20073ff1f0432b7c0dd172531185cc74d97f5da
Successfully built Kivy-Garden
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, certifi, chardet, requests, Kivy-Garden, kivy
Successfully installed Kivy-Garden-0.1.4 certifi-2017.11.5 chardet-3.0.4 idna-2.6 kivy-1.10.0 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22

C:\Users\Paulo>python -m pip install kivy_examples
Collecting kivy_examples
  Downloading Kivy_examples-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 10.0MB 44kB/s
Installing collected packages: kivy-examples
Successfully installed kivy-examples-1.10.0

C:\Users\Paulo>python share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py
python: can't open file 'share\kivy-examples\demo\showcase\main.py': [Err no 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\Paulo>
```

Comment: Esta faltando a biblioteca SDL TTF, você pode adquirir ela instalando a Lib Pygames.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787954/1518921 falta instalar o **SDL TTF library**, para instalar você pode baixar o *pygame* que já contém ele usando o comando PIP:

```
 pip install pygame
```

Ou então baixar os binários para Windows em:

- http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Se faltar o PIL (Python Image Library) você pode baixar os binários para instalação em:

- http://effbot.org/downloads/#Imaging

Comment: Instalei o pygame, mas ao executar o script de teste recebi a mensagem "No module named 'PIL'"

Comment: Conforme vi em alguns videos, o Kivy deveria ter reconhecido o SDL2 como editor de texto. Embora a instalacao do SDL2 tenha ocorrido 100%  o kivy não esta a reconhecer

Comment: @psalrod baixe o PIL destes link http://effbot.org/downloads/#Imaging

Comment: Recebi a sugestão para instalar o PIL, mas no site effbot só tem versões para o python 2.1 a 2.7. Estou usando a versão 3.6.2. Existe outra opção do PIL para a versão do Python que estou usando?